# PHP: where to put the Restful service code at right position?

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I am new to PHP and was trying to build RestFull service in PHP for my Mobile App. I googled and found [Create a REST API with PHP](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) Article best as per recommendations by many people on Stackoverflow and other places.

But while reading this article I arranged this code like below and was unable to figure out that the given last two functions, where to place them?

PHP is new language for me .. so please help me.

```
class RestUtils
{
    public static function processRequest()
    {
        // get our verb
        $request_method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        $return_obj     = new RestRequest();
        // we'll store our data here
        $data           = array();

        switch ($request_method)
        {
            // gets are easy...
            case 'get':
                $data = $_GET;
                break;
            // so are posts
            case 'post':
                $data = $_POST;
                break;
            // here's the tricky bit...
            case 'put':
                // basically, we read a string from PHP's special input location,
                // and then parse it out into an array via parse_str... per the PHP docs:
                // Parses str  as if it were the query string passed via a URL and sets
                // variables in the current scope.
                parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put_vars);
                $data = $put_vars;
                break;
        }

        // store the method
        $return_obj->setMethod($request_method);

        // set the raw data, so we can access it if needed (there may be
        // other pieces to your requests)
        $return_obj->setRequestVars($data);

        if(isset($data['data']))
        {
            // translate the JSON to an Object for use however you want
            $return_obj->setData(json_decode($data['data']));
        }
        return $return_obj;
    }


    public static function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
    {
        $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . RestUtils::getStatusCodeMessage($status);
        // set the status
        header($status_header);
        // set the content type
        header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);

        // pages with body are easy
        if($body != '')
        {
            // send the body
            echo $body;
            exit;
        }
        // we need to create the body if none is passed
        else
        {
            // create some body messages
            $message = '';

            // this is purely optional, but makes the pages a little nicer to read
            // for your users.  Since you won't likely send a lot of different status codes,
            // this also shouldn't be too ponderous to maintain
            switch($status)
            {
                case 401:
                    $message = 'You must be authorized to view this page.';
                    break;
                case 404:
                    $message = 'The requested URL ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ' was not found.';
                    break;
                case 500:
                    $message = 'The server encountered an error processing your request.';
                    break;
                case 501:
                    $message = 'The requested method is not implemented.';
                    break;
            }

            // servers don't always have a signature turned on (this is an apache directive "ServerSignature On")
            $signature = ($_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE'] == '') ? $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] . ' Server at ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ' Port ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] : $_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE'];

            // this should be templatized in a real-world solution
            $body = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
                        <html>
                            <head>
                                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
                                <title>' . $status . ' ' . RestUtils::getStatusCodeMessage($status) . '</title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <h1>' . RestUtils::getStatusCodeMessage($status) . '</h1>
                                <p>' . $message . '</p>
                                <hr />
                                <address>' . $signature . '</address>
                            </body>
                        </html>';

            echo $body;
            exit;
        }
    }


    public static function getStatusCodeMessage($status)
    {
        // these could be stored in a .ini file and loaded
        // via parse_ini_file()... however, this will suffice
        // for an example
        $codes = Array(
            100 => 'Continue',
            101 => 'Switching Protocols',
            200 => 'OK',
            201 => 'Created',
            202 => 'Accepted',
            203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
            204 => 'No Content',
            205 => 'Reset Content',
            206 => 'Partial Content',
            300 => 'Multiple Choices',
            301 => 'Moved Permanently',
            302 => 'Found',
            303 => 'See Other',
            304 => 'Not Modified',
            305 => 'Use Proxy',
            306 => '(Unused)',
            307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
            400 => 'Bad Request',
            401 => 'Unauthorized',
            402 => 'Payment Required',
            403 => 'Forbidden',
            404 => 'Not Found',
            405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
            406 => 'Not Acceptable',
            407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
            408 => 'Request Timeout',
            409 => 'Conflict',
            410 => 'Gone',
            411 => 'Length Required',
            412 => 'Precondition Failed',
            413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
            414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
            415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
            416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
            417 => 'Expectation Failed',
            500 => 'Internal Server Error',
            501 => 'Not Implemented',
            502 => 'Bad Gateway',
            503 => 'Service Unavailable',
            504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
            505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
        );

        return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
    }
}

class RestRequest
{
    private $request_vars;
    private $data;
    private $http_accept;
    private $method;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->request_vars     = array();
        $this->data             = '';
        $this->http_accept      = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'json')) ? 'json' : 'xml';
        $this->method           = 'get';
    }

    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function setMethod($method)
    {
        $this->method = $method;
    }

    public function setRequestVars($request_vars)
    {
        $this->request_vars = $request_vars;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }

    public function getHttpAccept()
    {
        return $this->http_accept;
    }

    public function getRequestVars()
    {
        return $this->request_vars;
    }
}
```

///// **Code srgments Which I am unable to put at right position**///////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 $data = RestUtils::processRequest();

    switch($data->getMethod)
    {
        case 'get':
            // retrieve a list of users
            break;
        case 'post':
            $user = new User();
            $user->setFirstName($data->getData()->first_name);  // just for example, this should be done cleaner
            // and so on...
            $user->save();
            break;
        // etc, etc, etc...
    }
    /////////////////////////////////
    switch($data->getMethod)
    {
        // this is a request for all users, not one in particular
        case 'get':
            $user_list = getUserList(); // assume this returns an array

            if($data->getHttpAccept == 'json')
            {
                RestUtils::sendResponse(200, json_encode($user_list), 'application/json');
            }
            else if ($data->getHttpAccept == 'xml')
            {
                // using the XML_SERIALIZER Pear Package
                $options = array
                (
                    'indent' => '     ',
                    'addDecl' => false,
                    'rootName' => $fc->getAction(),
                    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_RETURN_RESULT => true
                );
                $serializer = new XML_Serializer($options);

                RestUtils::sendResponse(200, $serializer->serialize($user_list), 'application/xml');
            }

            break;
        // new user create
        case 'post':
            $user = new User();
            $user->setFirstName($data->getData()->first_name);  // just for example, this should be done cleaner
            // and so on...
            $user->save();

            // just send the new ID as the body
            RestUtils::sendResponse(201, $user->getId());
            break;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link,

we can use CodeIgniter to create a RESTful API for your existing web applications, and demonstrate how to interact with your own API or other RESTful web-services, such as Facebook and Twitter.

[Working with Restful Services in CodeIgniter](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/)

May this helpful you.

Comment: I think you should also provide some summary before providing direct link. :)